# Difference between ls -l and ll?

Tags: shell, shell-script, ls

I'm relatively new to programming as a whole and some tutorials have been telling me to use `ls -l` to look at files in a directory and others have been saying `ll`.  I know that `ls` is a short list, but is there a difference between the other two?

Comment: You may want to take a look at `which ll`. You will probably discover that `ll` is actually an alias for `ls -l`.

Comment: So then what is the difference between `ls` any other command I put into the shell?  If I type `which ls` I get `alias ls='ls --color=auto' 
    /bin/ls`, but if I type (for example) `which cd` I get `/usr/bin/which: no cd in (........)`.  EDIT: I tried it again with `which mkdir` and I got `/bin/mkdir`.  What is the distinction between these commands that some of them are stored(?) in `/usr/bin` and some are apparently not?

Comment: this is an affect of your distro's default `$PATH`. `ls` is very often aliased, so your shell reports the alias (which takes precedence over the binary) and the binary's actual location (in your case, `/bin/ls`). If `which` could not find `cd`, then something appears terribly wrong.

Comment: `cd` is a shell builtin keyword, not a program found in a filesystem. Use `type cd` and `type ls` to see what I mean. Some commands are simply overriden by shell builtins: `echo` exists in `/bin/echo`, but in `bash` and in fact most of modern shells, a builtin `echo` function is called instead (which usually has extended features). `type` actually tells you which one it is.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

On many systems, `ll` is an alias of `ls -l`:

```
$ type ll
ll is aliased to `ls -l'
```

They are the same.

Comment: ll is aliased to `ls -ltr' - I am using red hat 6

Comment: in Ubuntu 14.04 ll is aliased to 'ls -alF'

Comment: Also `ls -alF` in Ubuntu 12.04, 16.04, and likely many more.

Comment: For me on macOS Sierra ll is aliased to `ls -lh`

Comment: zsh: command not found: ll :(

Comment: @Harinder zsh has the shorter `l`

Comment: I usually alias `ll` to `ls -Ahog` on Bash.  It shows long listing but without the owner and group column; it additionally shows human-readable sizes (with suffixes like K, M, etc.), hidden files and directories except `.` and `..`.

Comment: @legends2k still the same
zsh: command not found: l

Comment: RHEL8 = ```alias ll='ls -l --color=auto'```

Answer (score 20):

As noted, `ll` is often defined as an alias of `ls -l`. In fact, `ls` is often an alias itself:

```
$ which ls
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
/usr/bin/ls
```

The actual command is `ls` which above is found in `/usr/bin`. `ll` is intended as a convenience, but you cannot rely on it being defined on all *nix systems, so it is good to know what it is really doing.

Comment: Great answer.  I can't help by add that this is one of the reasons why relying on `ls` in automation (especially ad-hoc one-liners) is usually a bad idea.  It has several options that change its output, and many ways to specify them.  With different distributions choosing different defaults, it tends to lead to headaches.

Comment: I haven't seen any popular distribution to alias `ls` to anything else than `ls --color=auto`. It's either that or there is no alias.

Answer (score 10):

**Ubuntu 12.04, 14.04, 16.04, 18.04**:

```
laike9m@laike9m1:~$ type ll
ll is aliased to `ls -alF'
```

Comment: Also 12.04 and 16.04, but that is all I have available to test right now.

Comment: I can confirm also 18.04

Answer (score 4):

In most cases, `ll` does not work in shell scripts.

Comment: What happens is that typically commands like `ll` are really aliases, that aren't defined when running scripts.

Comment: Some people have the alias in the .profile, and the alias is working in an interactive shell.
After debugging/testing a new script, the script suddenly fails in crontab. Cron does not read the .profile.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, but should be a comment instead. From my little understanding, aliases are deprecated in shell scripts.

Comment: I say "most" but it does not on mine, and i use `ls -l`

Answer (score 2):

`ll` is an alias for `ls -l`.

The option `-l` tells the command to use a long list format. It gives back several columns, not shown when the simple `ls` command is used. These columns include:

- Permissions
- Number of hardlinks
- File owner
- File group
- File size
- Modification
- time
- Filename

Answer (score 0):

ll is actually aliased to `ls -l'
If you run ll, then it will show you files in the shell then you to press Enter to see the next files (more.. option). If you run ls -l, then all files will be displayed at a time.